# Changing sender's email address in Magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento, sendmail, php

Right now when Magento sends new account confirmation, order details, etc. to customers, it goes out from abccompany@bluehost.com. We'd like to send it from support@abccompany.com. How to achieve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can change this email Id from the system->configuration tab.

Comment: The configuration settings show the email ID I want. But when the mails get sent it is from the host domain (abccompany@bluehost.com)

Comment: hi,, you can refer this link.it may help you.

    http://webdevster.com/ecommerce/magento/setup-smtp-with-magento


Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the above script could to the trick. I'm on Bluehost. They don't allow me to use my Google Apps mail on port 587.

Comment: Found a hack here: http://blog.codelab.co.nz/2010/01/12/bluehost-wont-allow-gmail-smtp-connections/

Comment: how did you solve it? cause mine was getting the admin mail and from name.

Answer (score 11):

Go here

```
system->configuration->store email addresses
```

here you can find email addresses of General contacts, Sales Representative etc.

Change the email addresses here and

```
system->configuration->Sales Emails
```

Select the sender here it will change the sender email for all Sales Emails

and now go to   `system->configuration->customer configuration`  to change the new account email sender etc.

Thanks